# Does the 920 support 5 GHz Wi-Fi?

Tags: nokia-lumia-920, wifi

I'm thinking of buying a new home router. I can see that there are a lot of 5 GHz routers out there in the wild.

Is the 920 compatible with 5 GHz networks? (802.11n and 802.11ac)

Comment: Which device? Most higher-end Lumias should support dual-band 802.11n, and I believe the 1520 and 930 at least support ac.

Comment: I'm using the 920.

Comment: http://www.nokia.com/global/products/phone/lumia920/specifications, http://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_lumia_920-4967.php, http://www.engadget.com/products/nokia/lumia/920/specs, etc. In short: dual-band 802.11n **yes**, 802.11ac **no**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does, here is the spec sheet:
http://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_lumia_920-4967.php
Wi-Fi 802.11 a/b/g/n, dual-band, DLNA, Wi-Fi hotspot